# How to insert a ListView into a GvrView in Google VR?

Tags: android, listview, google-cardboard

I am trying to show a ListView in an VR app using Google VR.
My app shows a listview of images that - with one click - are displayed into a VrPanoramaView. From there it is possible to click the Cardboard symbol and enter the VR Stereo view. However this requires removing the phone from the VR headset every time you want to display a new image.
So I would like to enter cardboard mode when on the ListView (like the Cardboard App does) and remain in VR mode while I go through all the images (again as the app does).
From the documentation, I understand I should use a GvrActivity with a GvrView. However, it is unclear to me how to add the ListView to the GvrView. 
Am I on the right track? And if so how do you present the list in VR mode?
As I have never used GvrViews, I would be very grateful for a simple example